# Viability of openshift with docker images without the code. And operative of these cases

Tags: git, yaml, openshift, minishift

In openshift, I want to do the same, but I encounter some problems.

I created a persistent volume and a job who will do the 'git clone'.

After that, I defined deployments in this volume, with images that I upload to DockerHub.

This worked fine. But when I wanted to add ssh-key for a private GitHub repository... problems start. It seems that you cant add the ssh-key secrets to a 'job', only to deployments and builds.

¿It is a weird operation in openshift? ¿The images used in openshift often include the code? ¿You know any form to include to a job yaml configuration, the ssh-key of GitHub?

Thanks of advantage